# chrome - How to display images in popup.html using dom and js

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, dom, popup

I am doing a project and I need to display on a chrome extension popup all the images of the current selected tab website, I tried many things but the popup always shows as a small popup with nothing on it.

Here is the code:

Dom.js:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.action == "getDOM")
sendResponse({dom: document.body.getElementsByTagName("img")});
 else
   sendResponse({}); // Send nothing..
});
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "PrintIt",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Partilha conteudo com redes sociais",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
],
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "http://www.google.com/*"
    ],
    "js": [
        "dom.js"
    ]
}]
```

}

Popup.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script>
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  // Send a request to the content script.
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
  document.write(response.dom);
  });
});
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

I did console.log(response.dom) and i got the folowing errors in estension console:

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:236
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect miscellaneous_bindings:236
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'dom' of
undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined
 at chrome-extension://cfboppmcojfddlkbpohfnnnkogpeflgk/popup.js:4:23
 at miscellaneous_bindings:281:11
 at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:390:21)
 at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:376:27)
 at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:396:17)
 at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect (miscellaneous_bindings:239:27) event_bindings:380
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem some time ago. It's simply prohibited to place script code inside the popup.html so it's not working. Place your code completely inside of dom.js and everything should be fine.

Comment: Can i just simply make the popup.html '<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>' and create a popup.js with 'chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  // Send a request to the content script.
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
  document.write(response.dom);
  });
});'

Comment: Yes, you can define '<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script> in the header of your popup.html - this script will be automaticly run when the popup appears (you clicked on the icon) without the need for other voodoo ;) I'm not sure what exactly your script does - seems like I'm working in a more simplistic maner.

Keep also in mind that all scripts that you're defining in the manifest will have access to the current pages DOM.